# Restore mysqldump file without writing to general_log

Tags: mysql, diskspace

It's basically what the subject says. I've read about disabling binary log when restoring a DB dump, but I can't find how to do this with general log (all the INSERT statements end up there and they take a lot of space). Is it possible to disable this kind of logging just for the restore operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
And restart the server.

Comment: Thanks. Also, when reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-file-maintenance.html I learned that in some versions you can turn it off and on without restarting the server